# Modifying underscores to work with woocommerce

Tags: css, woocommerce

Woocommerce is trying to fit itself into the page structure of my site. This is the main structure -

```html
#primary {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 66.6%; !important;
}

#secondary {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 33.3%; !important;
}
```

What this means is that, for example, a single product page in woocommerce is fitting into the left hand primary which is only 66.6% of the width.

How can I get it to stretch across the full width?

Comment: Change the width from 66.6 to 100%?

Comment: Have you configured the WooCommerce wrappers to match your theme's? See the [docs](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility#section-2)